# What did Schrödinger call his cat?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> It’s your stubborn weight that never seems to change.
>   And how fast you are? Going in a specific direction.
>   Move without any vows—it all boils down to.
>
> So the *real* kid who karates,
>   Steal 1200 from him.
>   A stone which defined it, began with it.
>
> The snakes hissing within verse,
>   with deer without are;
>   it’s time.

**What did Schrödinger call his cat?**

Comment: Clearly Schrödinger's cat is called **Alf**, because it's 'alf alive and 'alf dead.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor   Very funny and appropriately placed in a COMMENT!!  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*It’s your stubborn weight that never seems to change.*
*And how fast you are? Going in a specific direction.*
*Move without any vows—it all boils down to.*

> Weight that never changes is **mass**, and speed in a specific direction is **velocity**. These quantities are usually represented by $m$ and $v$, which is also what's given by the third line: "move" without any vow(el)s is $mv$. In physics, mass times velocity is momentum, usually represented by $p$, which I think is the final answer for this verse.

*So the real kid who karates,*
*Steal 1200 from him. <s>One German stone—</s>*
*<s>the one who</s> A stone which defined it, began with it.*

> The actor who plays [the Karate Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid) is apparently Ralph Macchio, and 1200 in Roman numerals is MCC, so we're left with $ahio$? Also MCC equates to $mc^2$, and "One German stone" is clearly Einstein; both of these give the letter $E$, which I think is the final answer for this verse.

*The snakes hissing within verse,*
*<s>with an accent “The”;</s> with deer without are;*
*it’s time.*

> Snakes hissing suggests the letter S; with "in verse" gives $S^{-1}$. (Thanks to the OP for [help in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/68508) with this one.) <s>An accented "The" is surely "Ze", so maybe $Z$ (with the US pronunciation "zee")?</s> OK, it was "De" or $D$, also given by removing the R from "deer". So we have $S^{-1}D=T$, time, which is also given directly by the final line.

So the solution is

> PET ($P, E, T$ from the three verses)

which makes sense given the question.

Comment: Puzzle edited. @Randal'Thor

Comment: For the second part, use the Karate Kid actor and the given number written in a different numeral system to point to (part of) an expression that the German Stone was famous for. Sorry for the verbosity, I'm trying to avoid spoilers.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine I think I'm getting closer, but the middle verse is still problematic ... will go to bed and come back to this tomorrow.

Comment: Think about the first one a bit more. You get another letter from it. However, even then, that answer seems weird

Comment: "The snakes hissing with[in verse]"

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine OK, I think I know what the final answer is now. Still slightly stuck on the third verse ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor Riddle edited once again.

Answer (score 1):

After reading Rand al'Thor's answer and making a few minor adjustments

> I get E=MCC

then continuing on i am finally left only with

> C

The cats' name was

> Light

Comment: I could never have gotten through all the physics, so I'm just going to put a comment here, and maybe you or someone can build off of it.  You said you got "C," which you interpret as "LIGHT."  But isn't C the SPEED of light?  There is an answer above that plays a bit with "P," and "S(S)", and "DEE" or "D" and then "E.". All of this makes me again makes me think "Speed," or "Speedy."

Comment: @Rob.   you may very well be correct.